# Java: Adding an image to a JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I took some suggestions and have rewritten some of the code to implement the suggestions made and to make it more readable.  Now it won't compile. The compiler is complaining that it can't resolve the constructor on the JLabel.  I made a comment where the issue is.

```
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: goulartj
 * Date: 9/4/13
 * Time: 10:11 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class NewSwing implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textField;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JPanel panel;
    Image image;
    JLabel label;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewSwing gui = new NewSwing();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField("This is a text field and these are my texticles!");
        textField.selectAll();
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        panel = new JPanel();
        image = new ImageIcon("cuteKitten.jpg").getImage();
        label = new JLabel(image); //COMPILER COMPLAINS HERE
        panel.add(label);


        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, textField);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textArea);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);




        textField.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String text = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(text + newline);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

   /* class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 3, 4, this);
        }
    }     */
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!  You guys always treat me so well!

Comment: Are you sure it can find the image? Also, creating the image from a file every time you want to draw is ascenine. You're going to jack up the render time in a bigger application. You should create the image, pass it into the MyDrawPanel constructor, and use that image to draw.

Comment: Oh, and you should be calling super.paintComponent(g); in your paintComponent method

Comment: I'm not sure that it can find the image. I tried opening the image with IntelliJ and adding it to the project but that didn't work either.

Comment: Read the tutorial as I suggested in my answer. Then take a look at the table of contents where you will find a section on using Icons, which will show you a better way to load the image into an icon.

Comment: I see what you're saying about creating the image every time it draws, that is asinine. I'm not creating it at the top of the class.  I'm not sure what you mean by passing it into the MyDrawPanel constructor, though.  The constructor doesn't take an image as an argument, and I don't know how to make a new constructor that would. .. I'll bet I do before this is all over, though.

Comment: and finally, I understand that I am not ever calling the paintComponent() method myself.  So, how would I call super.paintComponent(Graphics g) ??

Comment: `Now it won't compile` - No where in my answer did I suggest you create a JLabel with an image. Read my suggestion again. Read the JLabel API to find the proper constructor and read the tutorial for a working example. You can't post a question every time you get a compile error. You need to learn how to read the API.

Comment: pass the ImageIcon into the JLabel, not the Image. `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html`. `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html`, As @camickr said, your life will get easier when you learn how to read errors, and the API. Those two things allow you to write just about anything given enough time.

Comment: Thanks guys i think i learned something here today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing custom painting to display an image???

The problem is that the component doesn't have a preferred size (since you didn't override the `getPreferredSize()` method) so there is nothing to paint.

Just use a JLabel with an Icon. It will look after painting the icon and determining the proper size. Don't reinvent the wheel. Read the JLabel API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on how to use labels for more information.

Of course you also need to make sure you are reading the image. That is easy enough to do you just add a System.out.println(...) to make sure the Icon is created properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing up, but it's located at the edge of the screen.
Just change:

`frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);`

to

`frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);`

and it should display properly in the panel in the center.

Comment: I tried the change that you've mentioned here, @hdtsn, but it didn't do anything.  More correctly, it covered the textArea with the myDrawPanel, but the image was still not shown on the panel.

Comment: Then are you sure your image exists and is in the correct location?